# Ruby String concatenation

Tags: ruby, string

I have an array

```
books = ["Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3"]
```

I need to iterate through this array and get a variable like this:

```
@books_read = "Title 1 \n Title 2 \n Title 3"
```

I tried this bit of code:

```
books.each do |book| 
   @books_read += "#{book} \n"
end

puts @books_read
```

But, the + operator does not concatenate the strings. Any leads on this please.

Cheers!

Comment: What do you mean the `+` operator does not concatenate strings? That's exactly what it does! (See [String#+](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-2B))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `join`: `books.join(" \n ")`

Comment: Make sure to use double quotes, otherwise the \n is escaped.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Array#join](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-join): `books.join(" \n ")`.

> join(sep=$,) → str
>
> Returns a string created by converting each element of the array to a
>   string, separated by sep.